# App_Code DB Connection

Tags: c#, sql, database, app-code

Having code on each page to open a connection to retrieve or insert data to/from the local database can be very time consuming if you decide to change something (obviously having to change all of it so the code remains the same layout)

My question is, is it okay to have the connection to the database in the appCode. Is there a risk of to many connections the same source or from the same location?

Comment: How would you move to another database if the connection string is hardcoded?

Comment: string is not hardcoded, string comes from the cfg file. i am trying to find out if having the connection to the database in multiple different pages or, having the connection in the App_Code have has any difference.

Comment: You can create a separate class in AppCode (In Fact it should be in DAL) that takes care of creating connection to DB and returning it to the caller. You can either return same connection object or return new connection object depending on your requirement.